# az aks get-credentials command returns the clustername in lowercase

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

when I run the `az aks get-credentials --resource-group ResourceName --name Clustername --admin` to connect to the cluster using azure CLI. This command return the clustername in lowercase, whereas the clustername in Azure portal is in Uppercase. Do anyone have idea why it returns the clustername in lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

That's because a cluster name in Kubernetes has to be an `RFC 1035` compliant DNS name. This puts a restriction for your cluster name to only include lowercase letters. My guess is, Azure Kubernetes Service lets you create clusters with upper case names for convenience, in the Console, but keep in mind inside Kubernetes itself, the cluster name will *always* be lower case letters. That's what you're getting from your command line.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can we check if cluster name is RFC 1035 compliant DNS name ?

Comment: You can read about it in the RFC document [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035#section-2.3.1).